# Getting error while trying to connect wsdl service

Tags: javascript, node.js

When trying to make basic authentication on wsdl server. I am getting error 403  invalid wsdl url message. How to solve this?

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'https://servis.turkiye.gov.tr/services/g2g/kdgm/test/uetdsarizi?wsdl';
var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer("myusername" + ":" + "mypass").toString("base64");

soap.createClient(url, { wsdl_headers: {Authorization: auth} }, function(err, client) {
});
```

Comment: The URL you posted is freely available, there is no need to authenticate.

Comment: When I enter on soap UI it requires basic authentication in order to use its methods.

Comment: Check the output of `console.log(err)` in the callback function. Make sure the response body is not `Authentication failed` (i.e. your username or password is incorrect)